# Two Criteria Xlookup with If & Else Statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code at VBA, where my main goal is double check between two tables on two separate sheets. I made very basic two tables that have a similar structure with my data(I have 150 lines at my original data so definitely need a vba solution)

Data on Sheet 1:
[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIJAh.png)
Data on  Sheet 2:
[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT2Vl.png)

The first part of this code is basically a double criteria xlookup code, thats gonna look at the ID & Release number @Sheet1, compare to @Sheet2 and then return the Stat of the particular cell.

However I want to create this part with an if/else statement, because if there is no match of these 2 criteria between @Sheet1 and @Sheet2, I want to ask excel to copy certain cells and paste it at a particular place-this will also change total number of rows so indeed we need a loop. (Exp. For cells that don't match copy the data from Sheet2 to Sheet1, to the buttom of the table).

Has anyone have tips for this task? Would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not so sure if I understand you correctly.
Anyway...

[image]

From the above image example :
Table in Sheet1 doesn't have ID 12345 and ID 456789 value has a different RELEASE

```
Sub test1()

Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rg1 = sh1.Range("A2", sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set rg2 = sh2.Range("A2", sh2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each cell In rg2
    Set LR = sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Set c = rg1.Find(cell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If c Is Nothing Then
            Range(cell, cell.Offset(0, 2)).Copy Destination:=LR
            Range(LR, LR.Offset(0, 2)).Interior.Color = vbCyan
        Else
            If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value <> c.Offset(0, 1).Value _
                Then Range(cell, cell.Offset(0, 2)).Copy Destination:=c: _
                    Range(c, c.Offset(0, 2)).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
Next

End Sub
```

The code above do these things:

1. add a new record to table_sheet1 from table_sheet2 if table_sheet1 doesn't have it. 
    Put a blue color to identify that this is a new record.
2. update existing record in table_sheet1 if it's ID match with the ID in table_sheet2 but it's RELEASE don't match with the RELEASE in table_sheet2. 
    Put a yellow color to identify that this is an update of the existing record.

[image]

The code assumed that table_sheet2 either has the same row data or more data than table_sheet1.

Another thing that I figure out what you mean:
The first condition of table_sheet1 has a blank STAT.
A. IF the ID and the RELEASE table_sheet1 are the same with table_sheet2, THEN fill the STAT value in table_sheet1 from table_sheet2.
B. IF the ID table_sheet1 is the same with the ID table_sheet2 but the RELEASE table_sheet1 is not the same with the RELEASE table_sheet2 THEN add a new record from table_sheet2 to table_sheet1. So here there will be a new row with a duplicate ID value in table_sheet1.
C. IF there is a data ID in table_sheet2 which not exist in table_sheet1 THEN add a new record from this ID of table_sheet2 to table_sheet1. So here there will be a new row with a new ID in table_sheet1.

[image]

After running the code:
[image]

```
Sub test2()

Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rg1 = sh1.Range("A2", sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set rg2 = sh2.Range("A2", sh2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each cell In rg2
    Set LR = sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Set c = rg1.Find(cell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If c Is Nothing Then
            Range(cell, cell.Offset(0, 2)).Copy Destination:=LR
        Else
            If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value <> c.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
                Range(cell, cell.Offset(0, 2)).Copy Destination:=LR
            Else
                Range(cell, cell.Offset(0, 2)).Copy Destination:=c
            End If
        End If
Next

End Sub
```

Still not sure though if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest your second code is exactly what I wanted to do!

Thank you so  so much.

I was able to write the first part of the code but the parts with the 'else' statement was new and a bit blur for me, your answers indeed helps!

Comment: Glad that I can help. Thank you.